# Apps list long time load

Tags: android, listview, android-drawable, android-package-managers

I have custom row that have app name and app icon but the list takes long time to load the apps because of the app icon, I get this list in async task, so what to do?

I got some warnings in logcat like:

```
ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources
```

This my code:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> listOfApps = packManager.getInstalledApplications(0);
int total = listOfApps.size();

for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    ApplicationInfo appInfo = listOfApps.get(i);
    AppModule app = new AppModule();    
    app.setIcon(appInfo.loadIcon(this.getPackageManager()));
}
```

Comment: Load the icon in the adapter so you don't load icons that are never even shown. Here is an example using picasso: https://github.com/jaredrummler/apk-parser/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/jaredrummler/apkparser/sample/adapters/AppListAdapter.java https://github.com/jaredrummler/apk-parser/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/jaredrummler/apkparser/sample/picasso/AppIconRequestHandler.java

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Jared i will try that, I am a big fan of your apps specially ROM Toolbox. :))

Comment: I made it, some icons not loading but i will try to fix that, Thanks a lot Mr awesome man.